# Android back button Not working

Tags: android

```
public class Myactivity extends DroidGap {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_myactivity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        this.finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.myactivity, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
          super.loadUrl("file:///asset/www/index.html");
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

In Above I need to go to the  index.html file when the back button is clicked.But  whwn i try it i get folowning error.

```
11-02 12:25:00.677: E/WindowManager(24344): Activity org.apache.cordova.example.Myactivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@421fad78 that was originally added here
11-02 12:25:00.677: E/WindowManager(24344): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity org.apache.cordova.example.Myactivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@421fad78 that was originally added here
```

Comment: Calling `finish()` in `onDestroy()` is not necessary. The activity is already finishing. And when overriding activity `onXxx()` methods, you MUST call superclass version of the same e.g. `super.onDestroy()`.

Answer (score 0):

the back button is supposed to finish the activity. Calling `super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)` you are asking android to call, `currentActivity.finish();`.

Comment: Hey now  i get this popup message A A network error occurred. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html")

Comment: do you have that file inside the assets? assets/www/index.html ?

Comment: check for  misspelling

Comment: No. Actuuly i can move to the page  sucessfully.But it gives the above error before it happens.I go the page after i click the ok buuton appeared on Alert box

Comment: button? Which button?

Answer (score 0):

override the `onBackPressed()` method. put your code in it.,it will work

Comment: nope. Appears warning: KeyCharacterMap - No keyboard for id 0

Comment: My answer was correct. I guess you are a new user that is why you are trying the downvote button on my answer. Good

Comment: I'm sorry. Yes, it was another problem.